# Can I remove the $ in bash C-style for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Have seen people using the following for loop

```
for (( i = 0; i <= $length; i++ ))
```

Can I omit the `$` sign in double parentheses to refer the variable `length`?

Comment: if that's how $length is defined

Comment: @Han : Yes, because you are in numeric context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you can do that as following:

```
length='10'

for (( i = 0; i <= length; i++ ))
do 
       echo "I = $i"
done
```

**Output:**

```
I = 0
I = 1
I = 2
I = 3
I = 4
I = 5
I = 6
I = 7
I = 8
I = 9
I = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, [ShellCheck encourages it](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2004).

Answer (score 0):

As your shell interpreter is bash, **if your length is known** I would recommend you using a neat feature called bash sequence expression:

```sh
for each in {0..10}
do
  echo $each
done
```

Comment: Have you tested it? (tip: it does not work)

Comment: You are right @KamilCuk, I wrongly thought that works. I edited my answer considering a known length value instead.